# Azure DevOps can't find python module

Tags: python, azure-devops, pytest

I am attempting to run tests from a python module using Azure DevOps. I've got a pipeline build set up to build off a yml file.
I'm getting an error that my module name on my imports is not right, but it doesn't look like that the module name is getting set in the build?

When I run this locally, it works just fine.

Module repo file structure:

```
api_check
api_check/auth
api_check/etc
api_check/__init__.py
```

I'm running the tests using the following in my yml file:
      - script: |
          mkdir logs
          pytest -m smoke --junitxml=logs/test-results.xml --ENV=prod
            displayName: 'Test with pytest'

This step is giving the following error:

```
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9825682Z _______________________ ERROR collecting test_search.py ________________________
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9826322Z ImportError while importing test module '/home/vsts/work/1/s/test_search.py'.
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9826804Z Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9827123Z Traceback:
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9827411Z test_search.py:12: in <module>
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9827745Z     from api_check.auth import get_Token_UsernamePassword
2018-10-11T21:51:02.9828644Z E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_check'
```

Is there something I need to add to get the build to recognize the module api_check? Is there some sort of build variable I need to read in?

Edit for more information-

I am running this from whatever the directory is that the yml file gets run from my default - based off the debug log, the working directory is `/home/vsts/work/1/s`. 
When I list the contents of the working directory, I see all the contents of my module, everything that in my repo is under `api_check`.

So, rather than what I would expect from pulling down a repo:

```
$workingDirectory/api_check
$workingDirectory/api_check/auth
$workingDirectory/api_check/etc
$workingDirectory/api_check/__init__.py
```

it is instead:

```
$workingDirectory
$workingDirectory/auth
$workingDirectory/etc
$workingDirectory/__init__.py
```

So it looks like just adding the parent directory `api_check` wouldn't help, as there appears to be no `api_check` directory. Is there some setting I can flip in the pipeline sources to have it include the top-level folder `api_check`?

Comment: The parent dir of `api_check` is not in `sys.path`. However, it's not clear from where you are running `pytest` to elaborate a proper solution; adding path of `api_check` parent dir to `PYTHONPATH` should be the quick-and-dirty workaround.

Comment: @hoefling I added further information in the main post about the directory situation.

Comment: So `api_check` is the git repo root? Check whether you can modify the `git clone` command in your Azure container (e.g. `git clone https://my.repo.git -o api_check`) to match the local directory structure. However, this is only a workaround; modifying your git repo structure, pulling the `api_check` package one level down would be more appropriate. Simply create an `api_check` directory in the repo root and move all the python files from root in there.

Comment: Yep, that ended up being how I fixed it. Moved it down a level. If you'd like to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it, or I can answer my own. Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and write your own answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, Azure expands the repo so that the highest level directory in the repo becomes the working directory, rather than being *in* the working directory.

To solve my problem, I moved my module to a second-level directory in my repo.

ex, GitHub repo layout:

```
$repo/api_check
$repo/api_check/auth
$repo/api_check/etc
$repo/api_check/__init__.py
```

becomes

```
$workingDirectory/api_check
$workingDirectory/api_check/auth
$workingDirectory/api_check/etc
$workingDirectory/api_check/__init__.py
```

There may be a way to make Azure expand the repo as a sub-directory in the working dir, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the `__init__.py` under the root directory, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Please, post suggestions as comments.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to execute your tests using below command: (use python -m)

`python -m pytest -v test.py`